Can I reduce this series of products of Bessel functions
In my research, I came across the following series:
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty i^{k+1}(n+k)e^{i(n+k)\theta}J_n(a)J_k(b).$$
This looks as if it might be reducable (Series of products of Bessel functions of the first kind).
Any help would be greatly appreciated .
EDIT:
For context, the motivation is to generalize the result:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}e^{i a \sin{\theta}}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}i n e^{in\theta}J_n(a).$$
To the case where the left-hand side reads:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}e^{i(a \sin{\theta}+b\cos{\theta})}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}?~e^{in\theta}.$$
What should be the coefficients of the Fourier series that appears on the right?
The original statement of the question shows as far as I got.

Your series can be easily simplified using the Bessel function's generating function:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty i^{k+1}(n+k)e^{i(n+k)\theta}J_n(a)J_k(b)&=ie^{in\theta}J_n(a)\left[n\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty i^{k}e^{ik\theta}J_k(b)+\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty i^{k}ke^{ik\theta}J_k(b)\right]\\
&=ie^{in\theta}J_n(a)\left[ne^{ib\cos\theta}-i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\theta}e^{ib\cos\theta}\right]\\
&=i\left(n-b\sin\theta\right) e^{i(n\theta+b\cos\theta)}J_n(a)
\end{aligned}
$$

This is correct. I can validate your answer. Although that doesn't help my purpose. I've edited my question to add context. Sorry for the confusion.
